# How can I determine who added permissions for an AD group to a folder's security?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

For SSRS, is there any way to determine who added permissions for an AD group in the folder's security? Someone added an AD group that shouldn't have been added... twice... I can't determine who is adding it. I have access to the database, but my history table is empty and I see nothing in the SecData table for who added those AD groups.

Related question: Why is nothing in history? I am guessing there is a setting to turn on tracking?

Comment: By default, a subfolder inherits the permissions from its parent folder.

Comment: Yes, but it would have broke the link to the parent folder's security when they changed security on this child folder. (A warning pops up, which I am guessing they ignored.)

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. **Was** the inheritance broken or **would** it have been? If the inheritance isn't broken, than the AD group may have been added to the **parent** folder.